# What statistical tools can I use to evaluate this data?

Tags: repeated-measures, sampling

I recently performed an experiment to implement Gamification (a simple points system) into a web application to see if the points had an effect on the users in terms of usage.

We have data on how much time users spend daily in the application, 1 month before Gamification was implemented, and 1 month after.
The users selected for the experiment were sampled into 3 different groups:

1. Control group (users who did not use gamification) - 300 users
2. Points group (users who used the points system) - 300 users, and
3. Performance group (top 10% points earners) - 156 users

**What statistical tools can I use to evaluate this data?**

All I have done now is to look at how the total time for each group changed from the first month to the next, and got:

1. Control group: +1%
2. Points group: +28%
3. Performance group: +49%

However, this is after I've removed what seemed to be outliers (new users appearing in the middle of the experiment etc.). Prior to this, it looked like this:

1. Control group: +41%
2. Points group: +105%
3. Performance group: +110%

Is this enough proof that the points did, in fact, have an impact on usage?

Comment: Just checking that the 3 groups contain the same people before and after.

Comment: @PeterFlom yes. For each group, there are the same people before and after. :)

Comment: See [this question and its answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs). Does that answer your question? If not, please say what else you are asking about